# Отслеживание нажатий

Tags: android, android-layout

Мне нужно написать приложение, которое бы отслеживало нажатия на экран и выводило определённую информацию. Как это сделать с layout созданным программно я знаю. Я не могу понять как отследить нажатие, когда экран создается с помощью ресурса -> `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы сделать обработку экрана созданного через ресурс, нужно создать объект класса Layout(или его подкласса) и установить ему обработчик.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
rl.setOnTouchListener(this);
```